# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) while switching android activities

Tags: android, android-activity, sigabrt, pjsip

I am trying to switch activities from within a listener for PJSIP-Calls,
but getting this error: `Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8613 (Thread-23469)`.

My listenercode:

```
    public void onIncomingCall(OnIncomingCallParam iprm){
        Log.e("SIP_Account", "Receiving Call" );
        SIP_Controler sip_controler = SIP_Controler.getInstance();
        SIP_Call call = new SIP_Call(sip_controler.getSIPAccount(), sip_controler.getEndpoint());

        if(sip_controler.hasActiveCall() ){
            //If there is an active call, decline the incomming call and send busy signal
            CallOpParam callOpParam = new CallOpParam();
            callOpParam.setStatusCode(pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_DECLINE);
            try {
                call.hangup(callOpParam);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SIP_Account", "Error while hanging up the incomming call " + e.toString());
            }
        }else{
            Log.e("SIP_Account", "Try to change activity:" );
            MiscFunctions.getCurrentForegroundActivity().changeActivity(VoIPViewCommands.RECEIVECALL, ActivityVoIPCall.class);
        }
    }
```

In MiscFunctions I got a code that allows me to access the Activity that is currently in foreground:

```
public class MiscFunctions {

static private TelephoneActivity currentForegroundActivity;


static public TelephoneActivity getCurrentForegroundActivity(){
    return  currentForegroundActivity;
}

static public void setCurrentForegroundActivity(TelephoneActivity ta){
    currentForegroundActivity = ta;
}
...
```

And TelephoneActivity is an extention of the SherlockFragmentActivity.

```
    /***************************************************************************************************
     * All activities in this project should extend this activity. This one will make sure that you can
     * always get the activity that is currently in the foreground of your app.
     *
     **************************************************************************************************/
    public class TelephoneActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

        public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            MiscFunctions.setCurrentForegroundActivity(this);
        }

        public void changeActivity(VoIPViewCommands extra, Class activityClass){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , activityClass);
            Log.e("TelephoneActivity", "Change the activity" );
            i.putExtra("Command", extra);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(i); //this is the line that leads to a crash 
//with 'Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8613 (Thread-23469)' message.
        }

    }
```

Can anyone explain to me what is the problem here?

Comment: You have excessively trimmed the error message.  Include a substantial amount of preceding and following lines to give it context.

Comment: The error message shouldn't be much longer in his case, if he didn't make any other errors as well. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal you are getting is an 'abort' signal, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) for a list of possible signals.

I guess your problem is with the **getApplicationContext()**.startActivity(i); here. Just write `startActivity(i)` here and you should be good.

Also notice [this part](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29) of the Android documentation about `getApplicationContext`:

> Return the context of the single, global Application object of the
>   current process. This generally should only be used if you need a
>   Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is
>   tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.